# Antlr3 (C# Target) Consistently Hits Phantom EOF Character

Tags: c#, java, antlr, antlr3

While writing an Antlr3 grammar in AntlrWorks (generating C#), I wrote the following set of lexer rules as follows:

```
array :
    '[' properties? ']' -> ^(ARR properties?)
    ;

properties :
    propertyName (','! propertyName)*
    ;

propertyName :
    ID
|   ESC_ID
    ;

ESC_ID :
    '\'' ESC_STRING '\''
    ;

fragment
ESC_STRING
    :   ( ESCAPE_SEQ | ~('\u0000'..'\u001f' | '\\' | '\"' ) )*
    ;
```

However, whenever I try to parse any string where the `ESC_ID` rule is matched, I hit a phantom EOF character at the end of the string:

Input: `['testing 123']`

`<mismatched token: [@4,15:15='<EOF>',<-1>,1:15]`

I know that the Java version of ANTLR's generated code is not thoroughly debugged, but I've managed to find my way around the quirks so far. Thoughts on how not to hit this error when matching this lexer rule?

**UPDATE**

I have now tried using the official C# port of Antlr3, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Reading files generally can result in an end of file character at the end of the file, on certain systems.

Comment: I'm parsing off of a string, not a file.

Comment: EOF just means it got to the end when it shouldn't of... Whats ESCAPE_SEQ? and whats the input string?

Comment: ESCAPE_SEQ is just part of the standard STRING lexer rule used in examples--I have another rule called STRING which is the exact same as ESC_ID, but enclosed in double quotes, and that works fine, so I don't think that is the problem. I'll update with the input string.

Comment: is there rules that are dealing with " [ on your input string?  because your strings start with '

Comment: Yes, there are rules to deal with `[`. Every other alternative in my code works, but any text that matches this rule has this error.

Comment: Can you include a minimal lexer and parser grammar top reproduce this problem? As is, it's hard to tell how that rule is getting used.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLRWorks can't be used to generate code for the C# targets. You'll need to generate your C# code using the `Antlr3.exe` tool that's included in the C# port. The preferred method is using the MSBuild integration, which can either be done manually or (finally!) automatically using NuGet.

The latest official release is found here:
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases

In addition to that, I have released an alpha build of ANTLR 3 on NuGet. If you enable the "Include Prereleases" in the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio 2010+, you'll find it listed as ANTLR 3 version 3.5.0.3-alpha002.

Comment: I am familiar with that problem. However, I am a Linux user, and when I tried to run the .exe with Mono on my files, I was handed an ugly stack trace having to do with a missing constructor. Hence why I was using AntlrWorks.

Comment: @BradRoss I'm in the process of fixing bugs for an update release. If you post the issue here, I may be able to get it corrected before the announcement: https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs/issues (It may be a duplicate of #4, which I'll definitely fix before the release.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just added the issue. I can't wait until the documentation for the Antlr4 C# target is done so I can migrate to that.

Comment: Updated now that I am using the C# port.